# Why is the connection refused?

Tags: python, networking, https, web-scraping, urllib2

I am creating a web scraping script and divided it into four pieces. Separately they all work perfect, however when I put them all together I get the following error : urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused. I have looked at similar questions to mine and have tried to catch the error with try-except but even that doesn`t work. My all in one code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import urllib2
site = ""

def phone():
    global site
    site = "https://www." + site
    if "spokeo" in site:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.get(site)
        content = browser.page_source
        browser.quit()
        m_obj = re.search(r"(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\*{4})", content)
        if m_obj:    
            print m_obj.group(0)    
    elif "addresses" in site:
        usock = urllib2.urlopen(site)
        data = usock.read()
        usock.close()
        m_obj = re.search(r"(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4})", data)
        if m_obj:    
            print m_obj.group(0)
    else :
        usock = urllib2.urlopen(site)
        data = usock.read()
        usock.close()
        m_obj = re.search(r"(\d{3}-\s\d{3}-\d{4})", data)
        if m_obj:    
            print m_obj.group(0)

def pipl():
    global site
    url = "https://pipl.com/search/?q=tom+jones&l=Phoenix%2C+AZ%2C+US&sloc=US|AZ|Phoenix&in=6"
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = usock.read()
    usock.close()
    r_list = [#re.compile("spokeo.com/[^\s]+"),
             re.compile("addresses.com/[^\s]+"),
             re.compile("10digits.us/[^\s]+")]
    for r in r_list:
        match = re.findall(r,data)
        for site in match:
            site = site[:-6]
            print site
            phone()

pipl()
```

Here is my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lazarov/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 48, in <module>
    pipl()
  File "/home/lazarov/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 46, in pipl
    phone()
  File "/home/lazarov/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 25, in phone
    usock = urllib2.urlopen(site)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

After manually debugging the code I found that the error comes from the function phone(), so I tried to run just that piece :

```
import re
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.10digits.us/n/Tom_Jones/Phoenix_AZ/1fe293a0b7'
usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
m_obj = re.search(r"(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})", data)
if m_obj:
    print m_obj.group(0)
```

And it worked. Which, I believe, shows it`s not that the firewall is actively denying the connection or the respective service is not started on the other site or is overloaded. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Sidenote: [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Sidenote: [Global Variables are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually the devil is in the detail.

according to your traceback...

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
```

and your source code...

```
site = "https://www." + site
```

...I may suppose that in your code you are trying to access `https://www.10digits.us/n/Tom_Jones/Phoenix_AZ/1fe293a0b7` whereas in your test you are connecting to `http://www.10digits.us/n/Tom_Jones/Phoenix_AZ/1fe293a0b7`.

try to replace the `https` with `http` (at least for `www.10digits.us`): probably the website you are trying to scraping [does not respond to the port 443 but only to the port 80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) (you can check it even with your browser)

Comment: When I tried it I received : HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable. Yet when that same fragment is on its own it works which makes me doubt that the web server unable to handle the HTTP request

Comment: Is there a way to check if that is the case and if it`s true to manage it.

Comment: yes, if you receive an HTTP error 503 (you may use a `try..except`) then stop for 5 seconds (`import time; time.sleep(5)`). to catch the error you may look at http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#error-codes (at the end of this paragraph there is a complete example)